# PySpark Keep only some columns from dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have several csv I need to process, all of them have more columns than the ones I really need from them, so I was thinking of getting rid of the columns I don't need to reduce the DF. I know it's possible to do something like

```
df.drop("column1", "column2", "column3")
```

Basically, specify each column I want to get rid of. I was wondering if it was possible to do the reverse, and tell the dataframe to just keep a list of columns instead. Because I need to keep 3 or 4 out of more than columns in each case.

Another approach I was told, is to select only the columns I need, get a new df from that, and truncate the original.

I'm kind of new to both Python and Spark, though I've worked with some PySpark in the project, but it has always been with a DB, not a file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this to drop the columns you dont need

```
df.drop("column1", "column2", "column3")
```

if you only want to select specific columns

```
df.select("column1", "column2", "column3")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Somehow, it didn't notify me about the response.

I'm gonna go with the select, because it's shorter to select only the 3 or max 4 columns I need, excluding all the others (there are more than 10 in each case; I think one has 20 columns). And after I get the columns, I can truncate the original DF to free memory (one of these files is massive)